# wrangler dev failed using @cfworker/web

Tags: npm, webpack, babel-loader, cloudflare-workers

I'm trying to deploy a project on Cloudflare workers using wrangler. I'm using the `@cfworker/web` package for routing. I've only setup a route at `/` for testing but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the dev output:

```
> wrangler dev

 ./node_modules/@cfworker/web/dist/application.js 31:30
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (31:30)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         }
|         catch (err) {
>             console.error(err?.stack ?? err);
|             if (err instanceof HttpError) {
|                 return err.toResponse();
 @ ./node_modules/@cfworker/web/dist/index.js 3:0-33 3:0-33
 @ ./src/index.ts
Error: webpack returned an error. Try configuring `entry` in your webpack config relative to the current working directory, or setting `context = __dirname` in your webpack config.
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "wrangler dev",
    "preview": "wrangler preview --watch",
    "build": "wrangler build",
    "publish": "wrangler publish"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.13.15",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "^2.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.36.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cfworker/web": "^1.6.11"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'worker.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        '@babel/preset-env',
                        '@babel/preset-typescript',
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
                    ],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

I can't figure out if there's something wrong with my webpack config or if there something else.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by changing the webpack config at line

`exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,`

to

`include: /(node_modules\\@cfworker\\web|src)/,`

It seems that the `@cfworker/web` module is using optional chaining and nullish coalescing and was excluded from the babel-loader.